# logind.conf not working, closing lid will not suspend laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, gnome3, suspend, fedora-22

I am running Fedora 22 on a Dell Latitude E6230.  At some point I got a software patch that broke the laptop suspending when I close the lid.  It was working, and now it is not.  I am not sure what patch caused this, or why.  I am also a newbie to Linux (but not computers), so sorry if I did not investigate something I should have.

What I have looked into:

- I tried un-commenting these lines in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
  and then rebooting:

  ```
  HandleLidSwitch=suspend
  LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
  ```
- ```
  sudo journalctl -b -u systemd-logind
  ```

  shows that the lid is detecting that it is closing and opening.
- I tried installing `gnome-power-manager`... but this seemed to have no effect.
- I installed gnome tweak tool and set "don't suspend on lid close" to "off". 
  In playing with this, I also changed "power button action" to "hibernate", yet the power button just turns the laptop off, and closing the lid still does not suspend it.
- I then went back to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and un-commented the lines:

  ```
  HandlePowerKey=suspend
  HandleSuspendKey=poweroff
  ```

  Yes, that is backward... but this setting did not take hold.  I.e., even after a reboot, the power button still turns the laptop off, and the suspend button will suspend the laptop.

  This seems to prove to me that the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file and the gnome tweak tool setting do not have any effect.
- I tried this command... but I am not 100% what it does:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup do-nothing
  ```

  I found this on one of the threads.  I did notice at this point that closing the lid while on the dock will suspend the laptop.  So I thought that maybe there was some double negative action going on.  I changed these lines just to test:

  ```
  HandleLidSwitch=ignore
  HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
  ```

  And the result is that the laptop no longer suspends while on the dock when the lid is closed, nor when the laptop is off the dock.
- At no time are any external monitors hooked up.

So what the heck am I missing? 
What can override these settings?

Comment: update: I got another software update. Now the laptop will suspend any time I close the lid, even on the dock. It should not suspend while on the dock as I have put the setting "HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore" back.    Also, and power and suspend buttons remain impervious to suggestions of change.  

still broken... just in a different way.

Comment: This did not work for me, but perhaps you can make it work: https://wiki.debian.org/ScreenLockingOnSleep  
I attempted to swap i3lock for xscreensaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by removing ignore-lid-switch-tweak program from startup programs.

From terminal run: `gnome-session-properties` then remove ignore-lid-switch-tweak.

Answer (score 3):

I arrived here because I had the **opposite** problem (lid closing was not being ignored, which is what I needed).

I had solved this issue once before, but it seems the latest versions of Fedora (I'm on Fedora 28 now), requires these two entries now, whereas before only the first one was necessary:

```
user$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf

HandleLidSwitch=ignore        <---- Set both of these
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore  <---- to ignore lid events.

user$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

I hope that helps someone else. Please don't downvote because I added a solution for the opposite problem. :)

Comment: I think that it would be worth adding a warning that restarting `systemd-logind` should be done with caution on a live system and you should make sure that no important unsaved data is open.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (xubuntu 20.04), I had logind.conf allright like so:

```
$> sudo cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf  |grep Lid

HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

BUT what was "inhibiting logind from doing its job I had to figure with this command:

```
$> systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block

WHO                 UID  USER     PID  COMM            WHAT                                                                       WHY                                  >
xfce4-power-manager 1000 riccardo 1838 xfce4-power-man handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch xfce4-power-manager handles these eve>

1 inhibitors listed.
```

Clearly the `xfce4-power-manager` was messing.

I opened `sfce4-settings-manager` -> `Power Manager` and there I found there were two options for Lid closed on docked or undocked laptop which I had to configure to "suspend". Did that and all worked all right.