# Korora Linux is not ignoring laptop lid close

Tags: linux, power-management, cinnamon

### Environment

Korora 24 Cinnamon (so a Fedora spin) on a Dell Inspiron 1525.

### My problem

I want to leave the laptop shut but not suspended. This is my media center computer, and it will reside shut even while in use.

I cannot get the system to ignore the lid being closed.

### What I've already tried

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23589/close-laptop-lid-without-suspend/ talks about using dconf-editor and go down a specific tree, but I don't have that tree. Specifically, I don't have a "Power" item. The tree they talk about is `Org->Gnome->settings-daemon->Plugins->Power` and attributes `lid-close-ac-action` and `lid-close-battery-action`.

Tell me, does the dconf-editor remind you of the Windows registry? Why can't this just be a file?

The same URL has a post about how to inhibit systemd from reacting to the lid when a certain process is running. That is not my goal. I want this to be overall.

My problem is basically the same as this guy's: [logind.conf not working, closing lid will not suspend laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/958594/logind-conf-not-working-closing-lid-will-not-suspend-laptop), but I'm on Cinnamon and he was on Gnome.

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/27808/preventing-lid-close-suspension/ This taught me about the /etc/systemd/logind.conf (`man logind.conf`) but my changes even after a `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

#### Final appeal

I want my laptop to continue normal operations even when the laptop is closed.

The logind.conf change didn't work. My dconf-editor doesn't have the right location (and there's no "add key" like in regedit), and gnome things don't apply to Cinnamon, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the Cinnamon power management window.
[image: Cinnamon power management window showing "When the lid is closed" option]

There are drop-down menus for `When the lid is closed` that include the option `Do nothing`, which works. I am uncertain of exactly how it works or how to do it programmatically, but it does work.